# best way to present hierarchical data python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I read about pandas multi index, but the examples I found did not cover this cases:

I have a set of measurements i in 1..n. Each measurement i consists of attibutes a, b, c, X, Y, Z. While a, b, c have scalar values, X, Y, Z are arrays.
(X, Y, Z have different length for different measurements, but within one measurement i, the arrays X, Y, Z have same length m).

Question: Whats the best way to represent this in a pandas data-frame?

The multi-index examples I saw would index data e.g. first level by i for the measurement and second level by k for index into X,Y,Z. But what about the attributes a, b, c that have just one value for each measurement, but not m? Should the a, b, c values be repeated? Or only the first row of each measurement i contains values for a, b, c, the other 2..m rows contain NaN?

Comment: Is there any relation between the indexed values of the arrays across rows? That is, for example, is the first element of the `X`-array in one row comparable to the first element of the `X`-array in some other row? And, how long are the arrays? What sort of operations does the data frame need to support?

Comment: X, Y, Z are relates attributes like coordinates of a point and each measurement i has up to 256 such points. a, b, c are other parameters of the measurement like e.g. a=temperature, b=voltage, c= number_of_points. Points between two measurements are somewhat related, but not strongly.
The queries that I would lie to do are like:

Comment: The queries that I would lie to do are like:
1) consistence check, that for each measurement i the number_of_point c equals the actually length of X, Y, Z arrays
2) e.g. select all measurements where X is larger than some value
3) check properties e.g. if a=1 there must be a point with X < 5

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comment, much of this will depend on the sort of questions you want to be able to answer at the end of the day. One example of a potentially meaningful representation, which takes advantage of the facts that the arrays have the same length within each row, would be to take the product along the arrays, repeating the $i$th row $m_i$ times;

```
In [12]: from itertools import chain

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 7, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 2], 'c': [10, 1, 1], 'X': [[10, 10], [10, 20, 30], [4, 5]], 'Y': [[20
    ...: , 30], [1, 4, 5], [0, 1]], 'Z': [[0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [50, 60]]})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
              X          Y          Z  a  b   c
0      [10, 10]   [20, 30]     [0, 3]  5  1  10
1  [10, 20, 30]  [1, 4, 5]  [0, 1, 2]  7  3   1
2        [4, 5]     [0, 1]   [50, 60]  1  2   1

In [15]: pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'a': np.repeat(df.a.values, df.X.apply(len)),
    ...:     'b': np.repeat(df.b.values, df.X.apply(len)),
    ...:     'c': np.repeat(df.c.values, df.X.apply(len)),
    ...:     'X': list(chain.from_iterable(df.X)),
    ...:     'Y': list(chain.from_iterable(df.Y)),
    ...:     'Z': list(chain.from_iterable(df.Z))})
    ...:
Out[15]:
    X   Y   Z  a  b   c
0  10  20   0  5  1  10
1  10  30   3  5  1  10
2  10   1   0  7  3   1
3  20   4   1  7  3   1
4  30   5   2  7  3   1
5   4   0  50  1  2   1
6   5   1  60  1  2   1
```

This assumes that the fact that the array lengths match across columns means that the arrays themselves are comparable element-wise.